# Excluding particular facet when creating project from predefined maven's archetype, is it possible?

Tags: eclipse, maven, war, websphere-liberty

I've created a **Dynamic Web Project** project based on this archetype: [webapp-jee7-liberty](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/com/ibm/tools/archetype/webapp-jee7-liberty/1.1/). This archetype add `jsf-2.2` facet to the project which I don't need and despite that I'm removing it manually this facet being added every time I perform *Update Maven Project* in Eclipse.

Can I change this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Would really love to see an answer to this. Drives me nuts that you can't just tell `m2e` or `m2e-wtp` to exclude certain stuff. I think some things can be done through lifecycle mappings, but I don't think you can get very granular.

Answer (score 0):

## Disable the "Java EE configurator(s)"

This will change the behavior upon import (and hopefully on update).

Go to: 
**Window->Preferences->Maven->Java EE Integration**

Under *Select active Java EE configurators*

Uuncheck the one(s) you don't want, e.g. *JSF Configurator*.

---

(Note:  In testing this quick I realized you might hope to use this against your existing Eclipse projects.  That could require a bit extra cleanup.  If you already have the facet set I don't think a "Maven->Update Project" will unset it.  You might need to do something like delete your Eclipse project from your Eclipse workspace, delete Eclipse project metadata like the **.settings** folder and do a new "Import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects".)

Comment: I think this is what @Andrei was suggesting, and I'm not aware of a way to do this at a more fine-grained (per-project) level.